# Is there more compact way to convert Map[Any,Any] to Map[String,String]?

Tags: scala, collections

Consider a code:

```
def convertMape(map:Map[Any,Any]): Map[String,String] = {
  map.foldLeft(Map.newBuilder[String,String]) {(builder,kv)=>
    builder += ((kv._1.toString, kv._2.toString))
  }.result()
}
```

Is there a more compact way to convert `Map[Any,Any]` to `Map[String,String]` without using map builder?

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
map.map{case (k,v) => k.toString -> v.toString}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for comprehesion,

```
for ( (k,v) <- map) yield k.toString -> v.toString
```